# Sometimes Picasso doesn't load the image from memory cache

Tags: android, picasso

```
 private class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    if (view != null) {

        String url = cursor.getString(CONTENT_URL_COLUMN);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final ImageView imageView = viewHolder.mImageViewIcon;
        final TextView textView = viewHolder.mTextViewName;

            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
             });
        }
    }
}
}
```

If list of images get already downloaded, then on fastly scrolling the list, 
**onBitmapLoaded()** method called and load the image from memory cache. But sometimes **onBitmapFailed()** called. Why ?

Comment: `Picasso p = new Picasso.Builder(context).setCache(new LruCache(24000)).build();`

Comment: Problem is still there.

Comment: Use https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Target` is being garbage collected because nothing is holding a reference to it. Picasso uses a `WeakReference` when holding `ImageView`s or `Target`s.

However, you need not use `Target` at all. Simply use the callback of `.into` and pass the `ImageView` directly.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView, new Callback() {
  @Override public void onSuccess() {
    imageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(GONE);
  }

  @Override public void onError() {
    imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
    textView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
  }
});
```

Comment: Target is necessary if you want to set the background of a GroupView like a LinearLayout.