# Picasso doesn't load image from cache in listview

Tags: android, caching, picasso, image-caching

I'm using Picasso for loading image on my expandableListview, but it seems like image caching is not working.

I have bunch of images on my list, and every time I scroll down and up, I keep seeing placeholder. I used use Universal Image Loader before, and it didn't show me placeholder when I already loaded image.

Here's my adapter and how I'm using it:

```
...

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ChildViewHolder viewHolder;
    mChild = (ArrayList<Item>) mChildWrapper.get(groupPosition);
    Item item = mChild.get(childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_child_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
        viewHolder.myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_img);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(item.getUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.my_placeholder)
            .into(viewHolder.myImage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    viewHolder.myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    viewHolder.myImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

    return convertView;
}

...

static class ChildViewHolder {
    ...
    private ImageView myImage;
    ...
}
```

I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732556/sometimes-picasso-doesnt-load-the-image-from-memory-cache) for caching, but it didn't work for me. What am I doing wrong here?